# Rector how to avoid formatting source code?

Tags: php, rector

When running a simple Rector rule `NormalizeNamespaceByPSR4ComposerAutoloadFileSystemRector` the source code will be completely formatted, line breaks and spaces that are used to beautify the source code are removed. How can this be avoided in Rector?

`$services->set(NormalizeNamespaceByPSR4ComposerAutoloadFileSystemRector::class);`

... is the only service config in rector.php.

Rector says "! [NOTE] File ..." will be added:" So according to the rule it creates a new file (actually it is the same file...). I susspect this looks new for Rector because of the added namespace by the rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Rector** doesn't have influence on that; the reformat happens because of how the PHP code parser works.

Rector uses [PHP-Parser from nikic](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).
It generates a tree of tokens (*AST* - Abstract Syntax Tree) and will reassemble it, afterwards transformations.
Unfortunately the parser doesn't (iirc, it *can't*) keep track of white-spaces.

I'm not sure there's any way to prevent that or reconstitute the original spacing.
Try to [follow the related GitHub issue](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/344).